# Kundera support for sharding?

Tags: mysql, rdbms, sharding, kundera

I am trying to make kundera to work with cassandra and mySql also looking for mysql sharding? Need some help with rdbms sharding with kundera.

Answer (score 1):

Got answer from Kundera developers that, kudendara doesn't support RDBMS sharding.